# Rendering Video Online

Tags: video, rendering, adobe-premiere

I've been scouring the interweb looking for a solution but haven't found one yet.  Hoping my fellow SO geniuses can help.

How can I have video rendered online?  I want to host an application on my server that allows my users to render their videos online.  So if you imagine using a web interface much like Adobe Premiere Pro to arrange video clips and pictures, set it to music, I need to then have the final arrangement rendered to mp4 or avi, etc.  Kind of like how Google creates its Google Memories, taking your pictures, adding music and rendering a video.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Online video editors or 'arrangers' are quite complicated and specialised and I doubt you would want to develop one yourself, unless you have some very long term plans or some very specific needs.

There are existing solutions which you can integrate into your site which sound like they might meet your needs - search for 'online video editor idk'.

One example is:

- https://www.wevideo.com/apis